# Apollo iOS convert JSONArray to String

Tags: ios, swift, apollo

Apollo iOS Swift does not convert JSONArray to String if you do not have object mapping in your schema.
I have a query where result array of Objects are not mapped in the schema.json
Description in the schema:

```
{"name":"stack",
"description":"",
"args":[
],
"type":{
"kind":"LIST",
"name":null,
"ofType":{
"kind":"SCALAR",
"name":"JSON",
"ofType":null
}}}
```

The received data looks like this:

```
"stack":[{ 
"name":"React",
"version":"",
"category":[ "JavaScript Frameworks"]}]
```

The error message I received is

```
[Apollo.GraphQLResultError(path: ["userHost", "stack"], underlying: Apollo.JSONDecodingError.couldNotConvert(value: {
    category =     (
        React
    );
    name = "JavaScript Frameworks";
    version = "";
}, to: Swift.String))]
```

Answer (score 0):

I could only solve this by altering `JSONStandardTypeConversions` file.
It was:

```
extension String: JSONDecodable, JSONEncodable {
    public init(jsonValue value: JSONValue) throws {
        guard let string = value as? String else {
            throw JSONDecodingError.couldNotConvert(value: value, to: String.self)
        }
        self = string
    }

    public var jsonValue: JSONValue {
        return self
    }
}
```

I changed it to

```
    extension String: JSONDecodable, JSONEncodable {
      public init(jsonValue value: JSONValue) throws {

        let string = value as? String

        if (string == nil) {
            do {
                let data1 =  try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: value, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted) // first of all convert json to the data
                let convertedString = String(data: data1, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) // the data will be converted to the string
                if (convertedString == nil) {
                    throw JSONDecodingError.couldNotConvert(value: value, to: String.self)
                } else {
                    self = convertedString ?? ""
                }
            } catch let myJSONError {
                print(myJSONError)
                throw JSONDecodingError.couldNotConvert(value: value, to: String.self)
            }
        } else {
            self = string ?? ""
        }
      } 
public var jsonValue: JSONValue {
    return self
  }
}
```

If standard conversion to the String does not work I am forcing JSON object to be converted to String. In this way, I am getting at least some data.

Comment: I have also facing this JSONArray to String issue, I applied this changes in my `JSONStandardTypeConversions ` file but still same error. `couldNotConvert(value: <__NSArrayI 0x281834330> to Swift.String`. Can you please guide any other way or something